# Hibernate custom connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports

I have some data in regular database tables, and some data are read from files. I want to leverage reporting tools facilities, so i would like "present" to the report tool my data as were they all were read from the database. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Read the data, from anywhere you want, in your application. Then build a list of objects obeying the JavaBeans conventions, and use a [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html). Jasper will iterate through the list of beans, and the field `$F{foo}` will have the value of the result of `getFoo()` on the current bean.

Comment: Ok, but this means that i cannot join data from my collection with data from the database. I was thinking to do the "mixture" at the hibernate level, if possible.